# How to get a list of all tables that have datatables applied?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I need a list of all tables that have jQuery DataTables applied. I searched the docs and the API but I could not find an array or something like that that holds the tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`$.fn.dataTable.tables()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/%24.fn.dataTable.tables%28%29) - DataTables's static function.

> It can be useful to be able to get a list of the existing DataTables
>   on a page, particularly in situations where the table has scrolling
>   enabled and needs to have its column widths adjusted when it is made
>   visible. This method provides that ability.